# Error while reading a file with GetFileAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have written this line of code:

```
file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///Images/Hair Cuts/HC_1.jpg");
```

But it throws this exception:

```
WinRT information: An item cannot be found with the specified Name
(ms-appx:///Images/Hair Cuts/HC_1.jpg).
```

This image does exist in the specified folder. Can anyone help?

Comment: Um, the reason is right there in the exception.

Comment: The image does exist in the folder.

Comment: Three slashes ///?  Try two.

Comment: ms-appx:/// should be correct. Make sure the images is builded as the correct type. And I'm wondering if the space has something to do with it. Try renaming Hair Cuts to HairCuts and alter the path, just to rule that out.

Comment: There is no file called "ms-appx:///..." Slash is an illegal file name character. It sounds like you want "ms-appx:///..." to be interpreted as a Uri, not a file name.

Comment: It does not work even with HC_1.jpg or /Images/Hair Cuts/HC_1.jpg or Images/Hair Cuts/HC_1.jpg. 

Anyway I used GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync as mentioned by Deani Hansen and it works fine. Thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retrieve the file, try using the code from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
using Windows.Storage;
```

.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///Images/Hair Cuts/HC_1.jpg");
```